# Can we consider (a bit) as a noun phrase in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, verbs, adverbs, phrases

> It’s a bit early to come to school.

A bit here is an adverb as it means a little.
(A bit) here can it be a noun phrase by itself even if it is not headed by a noun?

Comment: No: it's not a noun phrase. "A bit" is a complex paucal determinative modifying the adjective "early" to form the adjective phrase "a bit early". Although the article "a" makes "a bit" look like a noun phrase, it is actually part of the determinative, not a separate constituent, hence the term 'compound determinative'.

Comment: Note also that "bit" is not head of the expression "a bit", which has no head but is a single grammatical unit, a complex determinative functioning as a modifier.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think that "a bit" is not headed by a noun? From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bit):

> bit1
> noun
> 1 A small piece, part, or quantity of something.

Noun phrases often function adverbially:

> The ship is **a smidgen** too big for the canal.
> I've helped her **many times**.
> The opera is **three hours** long.
> Etc.

Comment: I don't think so!

Comment: @BillJ Yes, we analyze a sentence differently once again! I saw your answer, and I have no particular objection to construing "a bit" as a set phrase, without considering its internal structure.

Comment: My point is that a diagram of "a bit" would not show "bit" as a head, i.e. as a syntactic function. To call it a 'head' risks learners thinking that "a bit" is an NP, when of course it isn't. It's a complex determinative, like "a few", "a little" in their paucal sense.

Comment: @BillJ OK, I'll bite, since you've got me "a bit" curious now . . . How would you diagram the internal structure of that phrase, then?

Answer (score 1):

> *It’s a bit early to come to school.*

No: "a bit" is not a noun phrase. "A bit" is a complex determinative modifying the adjective "early" to form the adjective phrase "a bit early". It works in much the same way as the compound determinative "a little" does in the noun phrase "I have a little money".

Although "bit" alone is a noun, and the article "a" normally occurs with nouns, "a bit" is actually a single grammatical unit, a determinative, where "a" is not a separate constituent, hence the term 'complex determinative'.

Comment: Thank you so much.